# fetching the first image url of a blogger post when it's not hosted on Blogger

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, blogger

I am using a hosting service where I store the images I put on blogger.

The problem is blogger doesn't seem to fetch the image url to be the thumbnail of the when it's not uploaded/hosted on blogger.

(1) This is the script I use to display the posts on a post.
(I just copied it from what is provided after I download the template)
you can see it in action here > http://pr0x1ma1.blogspot.com/2016/12/test.html

(2) And here is the post with all external images in it > http://pr0x1ma1.blogspot.com/2016/12/test-long.html

How can I make those external images appear on those thumbnails??

(1)

```js
var showPostDate= false,
showComments= false,
idMode = true,
sortByLabel= true,
labelSorter= "sample label",
loadingText= "Loading...",
totalPostLabel = "Total Post:",
jumpPageLabel  = "Page",
commentsLabel  = "Comments",
prevText= "Prev",
nextText= "Next",
postPerPage= 100,
numChars= 0,
siteUrl= "http://pr0x1ma1.blogspot.com/",
imgBlank= "http://cm3inc.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/npa2.jpg";
</script>
<script>
//<![CDATA[
    function showPagePosts(t) {
var a, e, i, s, r, p, n, o, l = "";
0 === pagernum && (postsnum = parseInt(t.feed.openSearch$totalResults.$t), pagernum = parseInt(postsnum / postPerPage) + 1);
for(var u = 0; postPerPage > u; u++)
    if("entry" in t.feed) {
        if(u == t.feed.entry.length) break;
        a = t.feed.entry[u], e = a.title.$t;
        for(var c = 0, g = a.link.length; g > c; c++)
            if("alternate" == a.link[c].rel) {
                i = a.link[c].href;
                break
            }
        for(var m = 0, d = a.link.length; d > m; m++)
            if("replies" == a.link[m].rel && "text/html" == a.link[m].type) {
                var v = a.link[m].title.split(" ")[0];
                break
            }
        r = "summary" in a ? a.summary.$t.replace(/<br ?\/?>/gi, " ").replace(/<.*?>/g, "").replace(/[<>]/g, "") : "", r.length > numChars && (r = numChars >
            0 && numChars !== !1 ? r.substring(0, numChars) + "..." : "");
        var f = a.published.$t,
            h = f.substring(0, 4),
            _ = f.substring(5, 7),
            b = f.substring(8, 10);
        n = idMode ? ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "Mei", "Jun", "Jul", "Agt", "Sep", "Okt", "Nov", "Des"] : ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
                "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"
            ], o = showPostDate ? b + " " + n[parseInt(_, 10) - 1] + " " + h + " - " : "", p = showComments ? v + " " + commentsLabel : "", s =
            "media$thumbnail" in a ? a.media$thumbnail.url.replace(/\/s\d+(\-c)?\//, "/s500-c/") : imgBlank, l += '<div class="itemposts">', l +=
            '<h67><a href="' + i + '" title="' + e + '">' + e + "</a></h67>", l += '<div class="iteminside"><a href="' + i + '"><img src="' + s +
            '" /></a>', l += '<span class="summary">' + r + "</span></div>", l += '<div style="clear:both;"></div><div class="itemfoot">' + o + p +
            "</div>", l += "</div>"
    }
_results.innerHTML = l, _create_pagination()
}

function _create_pagination() {
output = "";
var t = 0;
if(output += (actualpage > 1 ? '<a title="' + prevText + '" class="prevjson" href="javascript:_init_script(' + (actualpage - 1) + ')">' + prevText + "</a>" :
        '<span class="prevjson hidden">' + prevText + "</span>") + '<em style="font:inherit;color:inherit;" class="pagernumber">', maxpage + 1 > pagernum)
    for(t = 1; pagernum >= t; t++) output += t == actualpage ? '<span class="actual">' + t + "</span>" : '<a href="javascript:_init_script(' + t + ')">' +
        t + "</a>";
else if(pagernum > maxpage - 1)
    if(minpage > actualpage) {
        for(t = 1; maxpage - 2 > t; t++) output += t == actualpage ? '<span class="actual">' + t + "</span>" : '<a href="javascript:_init_script(' + t +
            ')">' + t + "</a>";
        output += " ... ", output += '<a href="javascript:_init_script(' + parseInt(pagernum - 1) + ')">' + parseInt(pagernum - 1) + "</a>", output +=
            '<a href="javascript:_init_script(' + pagernum + ')">' + pagernum + "</a>"
    } else if(pagernum - (minpage - 1) > actualpage && actualpage > minpage - 1) {
    for(output += '<a href="javascript:_init_script(1)">1</a>', output += '<a href="javascript:_init_script(2)">2</a>', output += " ... ", t = actualpage -
        2; actualpage + 2 >= t; t++) output += t == actualpage ? '<span class="actual">' + t + "</span>" : '<a href="javascript:_init_script(' + t + ')">' +
        t + "</a>";
    output += " ... ", output += '<a href="javascript:_init_script(' + (pagernum - 1) + ')">' + parseInt(pagernum - 1) + "</a>", output +=
        '<a href="javascript:_init_script(' + pagernum + ')">' + pagernum + "</a>"
} else
    for(output += '<a href="javascript:_init_script(1)">1</a>', output += '<a href="javascript:_init_script(2)">2</a>', output += " ... ", t = pagernum - (
            minpage + 1); pagernum >= t; t++) output += t == actualpage ? '<span class="actual">' + t + "</span>" : '<a href="javascript:_init_script(' + t +
        ')">' + t + "</a>";
output += "</em>" + (t - 1 > actualpage ? '<a title="' + nextText + '" class="nextjson" href="javascript:_init_script(' + (actualpage + 1) + ')">' +
        nextText + "</a>" : '<span class="nextjson hidden">' + nextText + "</span>"), _pagination.innerHTML = output, _totalposts.innerHTML =
    totalPostLabel + " " + postsnum + " - " + jumpPageLabel + " " + (actualpage * postPerPage - (postPerPage - 1)) + (t - 1 > actualpage ? " - " +
        actualpage * postPerPage : "")
}

function _init_script(t) {
var a, e, i = t * postPerPage - (postPerPage - 1),
    s = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0],
    r = sortByLabel ? siteUrl + "/feeds/posts/summary/-/" + labelSorter + "?start-index=" + i : siteUrl + "/feeds/posts/summary?start-index=" + i;
1 == firstpage && (document.documentElement.scrollTop = _results.offsetTop - 30, document.body.scrollTop = _results.offsetTop - 30, a = document.getElementById(
        "TEMPORAL"), a.parentNode.removeChild(a)), _results.innerHTML = '<div id="loadingscript">' + loadingText + "</div>", _pagination.innerHTML = "",
    _totalposts.innerHTML = "", e = document.createElement("script"), e.type = "text/javascript", e.src = r + "&max-results=" + postPerPage +
    "&orderby=published&alt=json-in-script&callback=showPagePosts", e.id = "TEMPORAL", s.appendChild(e), firstpage = 1, actualpage = t
}
var minpage = 6,
maxpage = 10,
firstpage = 0,
pagernum = 0,
postsnum = 0,
actualpage = 1;
document.write(
'<div id="toc-outer"><div id="results"></div><div id="itempager" style="position:relative;"><div id="pagination"></div><div id="totalposts"></div><a title="Taufik Nurrohman" style="display:block!important;visibility:visible!important;opacity:1!important;position:absolute;bottom:10px;right:14px;font:normal bold 8px Arial,Sans-Serif!important;color:#666;text-shadow:0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.1);text-decoration:none;" href="http://hompimpaalaihumgambreng.blogspot.com/2012/03/daftar-isi-blogger-dengan-navigasi.html" target="_blank">&#9658;TN</a></div></div>'
);
var _results = document.getElementById("results"),
_pagination = document.getElementById("pagination"),
_totalposts = document.getElementById("totalposts");
window.onload = function() {
_init_script(1)
};
//]]>
</script>
<style>.comments-fb{display:none}#comments,.comments{display:none}h1.entry-title{background:#FF6B58;position:relative;padding:20px 0 30px;overflow:hidden;box-shadow:inset 0 -30px 30px -35px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);text-align:center;color:rgba(255,255,255,0.8);margin:0}h1.entry-title:after{content:"";background:url(http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-uCvqypLwH8A/VeV8F3H9CwI/AAAAAAAAElI/FgPlZg_b0D4/s1600/tp_slide.png)no-repeat center;position:absolute;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;top:0;opacity:.05}</style>
```

Can you help me how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to parse it from the HTML content of the post. To do that, you will have to change the endpoint to where you are sending the request (The full feed instead of the summarized version) as well handle the condition when the image is not hosted on Blogger. The code will change as follows -

```
<script>
//<![CDATA[
function showPagePosts(t) {
    var a, e, i, s, r, p, n, o, l = "";
    0 === pagernum && (postsnum = parseInt(t.feed.openSearch$totalResults.$t), pagernum = parseInt(postsnum / postPerPage) + 1);
    for(var u = 0; postPerPage > u; u++)
        if("entry" in t.feed) {
            if(u == t.feed.entry.length) break;
            a = t.feed.entry[u], e = a.title.$t;
            for(var c = 0, g = a.link.length; g > c; c++)
                if("alternate" == a.link[c].rel) {
                    i = a.link[c].href;
                    break
                }
            for(var m = 0, d = a.link.length; d > m; m++)
                if("replies" == a.link[m].rel && "text/html" == a.link[m].type) {
                    var v = a.link[m].title.split(" ")[0];
                    break
                }
            r = "summary" in a ? a.summary.$t.replace(/<br ?\/?>/gi, " ").replace(/<.*?>/g, "").replace(/[<>]/g, "") : "", r.length > numChars && (r =
                numChars >
                0 && numChars !== !1 ? r.substring(0, numChars) + "..." : "");
            var f = a.published.$t,
                h = f.substring(0, 4),
                _ = f.substring(5, 7),
                b = f.substring(8, 10);
            n = idMode ? ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "Mei", "Jun", "Jul", "Agt", "Sep", "Okt", "Nov", "Des"] : ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
                    "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"
                ], o = showPostDate ? b + " " + n[parseInt(_, 10) - 1] + " " + h + " - " : "", p = showComments ? v + " " + commentsLabel : "", s =
                "media$thumbnail" in a ? a.media$thumbnail.url.replace(/\/s\d+(\-c)?\//, "/s500-c/") : a.content.$t.match(/src\s*=\s*"([^"]+)"/) ? a.content
                .$t.match(/src\s*=\s*"([^"]+)"/)[1] : imgBlank, l += '<div class="itemposts">', l +=
                '<h67><a href="' + i + '" title="' + e + '">' + e + "</a></h67>", l += '<div class="iteminside"><a href="' + i + '"><img src="' + s +
                '" /></a>', l += '<span class="summary">' + r + "</span></div>", l += '<div style="clear:both;"></div><div class="itemfoot">' + o + p +
                "</div>", l += "</div>"
        }
    _results.innerHTML = l, _create_pagination()
}

function _create_pagination() {
    output = "";
    var t = 0;
    if(output += (actualpage > 1 ? '<a title="' + prevText + '" class="prevjson" href="javascript:_init_script(' + (actualpage - 1) + ')">' + prevText +
            "</a>" :
            '<span class="prevjson hidden">' + prevText + "</span>") + '<em style="font:inherit;color:inherit;" class="pagernumber">', maxpage + 1 >
        pagernum)
        for(t = 1; pagernum >= t; t++) output += t == actualpage ? '<span class="actual">' + t + "</span>" : '<a href="javascript:_init_script(' + t +
            ')">' +
            t + "</a>";
    else if(pagernum > maxpage - 1)
        if(minpage > actualpage) {
            for(t = 1; maxpage - 2 > t; t++) output += t == actualpage ? '<span class="actual">' + t + "</span>" : '<a href="javascript:_init_script(' + t +
                ')">' + t + "</a>";
            output += " ... ", output += '<a href="javascript:_init_script(' + parseInt(pagernum - 1) + ')">' + parseInt(pagernum - 1) + "</a>", output +=
                '<a href="javascript:_init_script(' + pagernum + ')">' + pagernum + "</a>"
        } else if(pagernum - (minpage - 1) > actualpage && actualpage > minpage - 1) {
        for(output += '<a href="javascript:_init_script(1)">1</a>', output += '<a href="javascript:_init_script(2)">2</a>', output += " ... ", t =
            actualpage -
            2; actualpage + 2 >= t; t++) output += t == actualpage ? '<span class="actual">' + t + "</span>" : '<a href="javascript:_init_script(' + t +
            ')">' +
            t + "</a>";
        output += " ... ", output += '<a href="javascript:_init_script(' + (pagernum - 1) + ')">' + parseInt(pagernum - 1) + "</a>", output +=
            '<a href="javascript:_init_script(' + pagernum + ')">' + pagernum + "</a>"
    } else
        for(output += '<a href="javascript:_init_script(1)">1</a>', output += '<a href="javascript:_init_script(2)">2</a>', output += " ... ", t = pagernum -
            (
                minpage + 1); pagernum >= t; t++) output += t == actualpage ? '<span class="actual">' + t + "</span>" : '<a href="javascript:_init_script(' +
            t +
            ')">' + t + "</a>";
    output += "</em>" + (t - 1 > actualpage ? '<a title="' + nextText + '" class="nextjson" href="javascript:_init_script(' + (actualpage + 1) + ')">' +
            nextText + "</a>" : '<span class="nextjson hidden">' + nextText + "</span>"), _pagination.innerHTML = output, _totalposts.innerHTML =
        totalPostLabel + " " + postsnum + " - " + jumpPageLabel + " " + (actualpage * postPerPage - (postPerPage - 1)) + (t - 1 > actualpage ? " - " +
            actualpage * postPerPage : "")
}

function _init_script(t) {
    var a, e, i = t * postPerPage - (postPerPage - 1),
        s = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0],
        r = sortByLabel ? siteUrl + "/feeds/posts/default/-/" + labelSorter + "?start-index=" + i : siteUrl + "/feeds/posts/default?start-index=" + i;
    1 == firstpage && (document.documentElement.scrollTop = _results.offsetTop - 30, document.body.scrollTop = _results.offsetTop - 30, a = document.getElementById(
            "TEMPORAL"), a.parentNode.removeChild(a)), _results.innerHTML = '<div id="loadingscript">' + loadingText + "</div>", _pagination.innerHTML = "",
        _totalposts.innerHTML = "", e = document.createElement("script"), e.type = "text/javascript", e.src = r + "&max-results=" + postPerPage +
        "&orderby=published&alt=json-in-script&callback=showPagePosts", e.id = "TEMPORAL", s.appendChild(e), firstpage = 1, actualpage = t
}
var minpage = 6,
    maxpage = 10,
    firstpage = 0,
    pagernum = 0,
    postsnum = 0,
    actualpage = 1;
document.write(
    '<div id="toc-outer"><div id="results"></div><div id="itempager" style="position:relative;"><div id="pagination"></div><div id="totalposts"></div><a title="Taufik Nurrohman" style="display:block!important;visibility:visible!important;opacity:1!important;position:absolute;bottom:10px;right:14px;font:normal bold 8px Arial,Sans-Serif!important;color:#666;text-shadow:0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.1);text-decoration:none;" href="http://hompimpaalaihumgambreng.blogspot.com/2012/03/daftar-isi-blogger-dengan-navigasi.html" target="_blank">&#9658;TN</a></div></div>'
);
var _results = document.getElementById("results"),
    _pagination = document.getElementById("pagination"),
    _totalposts = document.getElementById("totalposts");
window.onload = function() {
    _init_script(1)
};
//]]>
</script>
```